# JSON result - JavaMe

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I wish to get this as my json

```
{"image1.bmp": 
  {"description": "OK", "filename": "image1.bmp"}, 
{"image2.bmp": 
  {"description": "OK", "filename": "image2.bmp"}, 
{"image3.bmp": 
  {"description": "OK", "filename": "image3.bmp"}
}
```

but right now I am getting this instead

```
{"image1.bmp": 
  {"description": "OK", "filename": "image1.bmp"}
} 
{"image2.bmp": 
  {"description": "OK", "filename": "image2.bmp"}
} 
{"image3.bmp": 
  {"description": "OK", "filename": "image3.bmp"}
}
```

This is the code I have for JSON so far

```
public void toJSON(JSONObject outer,String description, String imageName)
{
  JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
  try 
  { 
    outer.put(imageName, inner);
    inner.put("description", description);
    inner.put("filename", imageName);
  } 
  catch (JSONException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

And

```
toJSON(outer,"description:" + e.toString(), "filename:" + imageName);       
out.write(outer.toString().getBytes())
```

Comment: Looking at [http://www.json.org], what you describe as the desired outcome isn't valid JSON since the expression after the first `},` isn't a string, but an object.

Comment: When I changed it to String, it is still the same json result.

Comment: It appears that the JSON that you are trying to create is representing on object (image1.bmp) that has two additional objects (image2.bmp and image3.bmp) as part of its contents.  Is that really what you want?  Maybe you could provide some more information about what your goal is.

Comment: I'll try and be explicit here: `{"image1.bmp": {"description": "OK", "filename": "image1.bmp"}, {"image2.bmp":...` The last part starting with `{"image2.bmp":` is invalid JSON. Look at the description of JSON at [http://json.org] It lists an object containing pairs of <string>:<value>. What you want has an <object> where a <string> should be.

Comment: Right now each time i read an image, it will be written as JSON. But I am trying to read all images before it is written as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects in the output you want aren't valid JSON, unless you put a } at the end of each object. Also, it looks like you want to add the images into an array, in JSON the arrays are between [ and ].

Simple solution: put each "outer"-JSONObjects to JSONArray and then call the arrays' toString():

```
public class JSONtest
{

    @Test
    public void test() throws JSONException
    {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject im = new JSONObject();       
        toJSON(im, "Ok", "image1.bmp");
        array.put(im);

        im = new JSONObject();      
        toJSON(im, "Ok", "image2.bmp");
        array.put(im);

        im = new JSONObject();      
        toJSON(im, "Ok", "image3.bmp");
        array.put(im);

        System.out.println(array.toString());
    }

    public void toJSON(JSONObject outer,String description, String imageName)
    {
      JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
      try 
      { 
        outer.put(imageName, inner);
        inner.put("description", description);
        inner.put("filename", imageName);
      } 
      catch (JSONException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }

}
```

Output (formatted):

```
[
   {
      "image1.bmp":{
         "description":"Ok",
         "filename":"image1.bmp"
      }
   },
   {
      "image2.bmp":{
         "description":"Ok",
         "filename":"image2.bmp"
      }
   },
   {
      "image3.bmp":{
         "description":"Ok",
         "filename":"image3.bmp"
      }
   }
]
```

There are also many [JSON-formatters and validators](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) floating around the net, which can come pretty handy once your JSON-strings are 10000+ characters long and contain deep nesting.